# return all empty folders in a document library using webservice

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-services, spservices

For a client I'm looking at the following case:

They have all sorts of documents within a document library grouped into folders (multiple levels deep). If a folder doesn't contain a document, the process owner knows that something is wrong since it's not complete. They want to be able to manually start a workflow to check a particular folder for completeness. If it's empty an email must be send with the name of the folder.

I was thinking of using SharePoint Online 2013 workflow however there is no action available to check if a folder is empty or not. So my second thought was using a webservice to do it for me, but I need some guidance on how to do that.

- Can this be done by leveraging the default web services from SP2013 Online?
- How can I check if a folder is empty?

I am not a programmer, but I know how to write some code. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks, 
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use SharePoint Rest Services and then calling:

```
   https://<weburl>/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('</sites/site/subsite/library>')/Folders
```

Just loop through all the results and when ItemCount = 0 and Name of the folder is not equal to Forms(default in every library) send out an email.

It does not list out the subfolders. Still thinking about a proper solution for getting all of the sub folders.

Refrences how to apply in workflows:

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Answer (score 2):

It could be done by leveraging [SharePoint REST services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx).

In SharePoint 2013 workflows  was introduced  a new action named `Call HTTP Web Service`. This action is flexible enough  to make requests to a variety web services including SharePoint REST service.

The following REST request demonstrates how to determine whether Folder contains items:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/[web]/[list]/[folder]')?$select=ItemCount
```

> Note: the query returns the count of items (`File` or `Folder` type) stored in the specified folder.

### References

- [Working with Web Services in SharePoint 2013 Workflows using
  SharePoint Designer 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558(v=office.15).aspx)
- [How to work with web service using “Call HTTP Web Service” action in
  SharePoint Designer 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/05/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks good. I will try that approach!